# eval alternative in Matlab reading from the workspace

Tags: matlab

I'm reading a matrix from a .mat file. What is an alternative for eval in this case?

```
load([folder filename]);
a = eval(filename(1:end-4))*16
```

I have heard eval is too slow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read a mat file like this and it does contain a matrix then you don't need an `eval` statement:

```
mat = load([folder filename]);
[a,matrixName,ext] = fileparts(filename);
a   = mat.(matrixName) * 16;
```

Please check the contents of `mat`.

Comment: well, I'm looping over a lot of files with different matrix names. but filename is always the matrix name too except it has .mat at the end...

Comment: @Kiarash I have changed the code, this way you can use it, use the `(matrixName)` like this, it is called Dynamic Field Access.